# Workaround for web-view blocking google authentication within a web application

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, google-authentication

Good Morning,

So I am facing a dilemma using Firebase Auth (specifically Google OAuth).
Google seems to have blocked the use of their OAuth when a user access my site via a web-view (for example they have clicked on the link in TikTok and the website has opened within a view in TikTok)

It makes sense as to why Google has blocked this, however, this is now stopping my ads from being successful as users see the ad, click on the link, and then it opens up in the TikTok web view, and then they can't log into my web application.

I'm using the simple Firebase Authentication plugin, with [Nuxt/Firebase](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/) the code for it is as below:

```
const provider = new this.$fireModule.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: 'select_account'
  })
  this.$fire.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
```

Does anyone know any workaround? I've googled this so much but the only real solution I have come across is if I'm creating an android/ios app and ***this is not a mobile application***, this is just a web application.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Did you find any solution, i'm facing this issue as well and i was not able to find anything...